# Regex for JS output from Flickr

Tags: javascript, regex, flickr

I use the [Flickr badge Javascript](http://www.flickr.com/badge.gne) on my site, but the image size options are limited. So I thought maybe a regex could help because Flickr provides much more image sizes (just not via the badge script), I’m not sure though if this works because the list of images (as in the html) can’t be viewed if you click "view source", only via Firebug/Safari Element Information.

All image urls end with an underscore and a specific character for the image size, so I want to replace `_t.jpg" alt="A Picture from Flickr"` with `_q.jpg" alt="A Picture from Flickr"` because **_t** stands for 75px square thumbnail and **_q** stands for 150px square thumbnail (which is the size I would like to have.

You can see the badge in action here on my [homepage](http://martensen.co/).

Is that possible and if yes, how?

Comment: What do you want to do? Change that suffix of what?

Comment: No not the suffix, I want to change _t.jpg to _q.jpg

Comment: And I think the problem is that the page loads, the JS asks Flickr for some images, Flickr delivers those images, the browser starts downloading them and THEN —much too late— the regex kicks in changes _t to _q and the browser starts downloading images again, right?

Comment: Exactly. I don't know if and I highly doubt there's a way to prevent the scripts to load the first bunch of thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (supposing that `images` is the collection of your thumbnails)

```
for (var i = 0, il = images.length; i < il; i++)
    images[i].href = images[i].href.replace(/_t\.jpg/g, "_q.jpg");
```

Comment: Hmmm, this is a url for a 75px small image: http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3066/2886271582_57f641507a_t.jpg and this is the same image as 150px: http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3066/2886271582_57f641507a_q.jpg — No idea where you got that _images_ from and what to do with it. Sorry ;)

Comment: *You* have to create that `images` array! Using `getElementsByClassName` or any other selector that fits a Flickr board. I don't know what's the DOM structure of the page and you didn't provide any code of it, so you have to figure it out on your own.

Comment: Whoops, an exclamation mark. Sorry dude. I thought posting the link to my homepage would be enough for someone to figure it out and give me some code and tell me to put it right before `</body>` or something. Guess that was a bit naive. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source of your site, the link to the flickr script looks like this:

```
src="http://www.flickr.com/badge_code_v2.gne?count=6&amp;display=random&amp;&amp;source=user&amp;user=8066182@N06&amp;size=s"
```

I'm not familiar with flickr, but could you change the size parameter, at the end, to 'm' (medium) or 'l' (large)?

If that fails and you don't often change the pics, you can use firebug to copy the script and manually change the filenames. Then refer to your local script instead of the one hosted on flicker.

Comment: Nope, the script allows only 3 sizes, and the one I want is not supported, that’s why I thought about the regex. This could all be done via the Flickr API, but unfortunately nobody did yet, and I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Nevermind, found a plugin for WordPress & Flickr which, after some editing, can do what I want. Contact me at martensen.co/ if you’re interested.